# How to handle application start event in ASP.NET module

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I am writing an asp.net HTTP module which needs to read configuration data *once* from a local file (say config.xml stored in application root directory) and then based on configuration perform some processing on incoming requests.

Since there is no Application_Start/Application_init hooking available in Asp.NET modules, what would be the best way to handle the scenario. I am trying to avoid reading configuration file each time a request comes. Ideally, I want to read the config file when application starts.

I need to code this in http module only and do not want to use Global.asax

Comment: Why dont you use static variables for this? Static means for all Sessions.

Comment: Static class objects are initialized only on first access, not when the IIS app pool starts up.  The Application_Start handler is better if initialization must be immediate on startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static variable did the trick. here is the code if someone is interested -

```
static string test; 
        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {


            application.BeginRequest +=(new EventHandler(this.Application_BeginRequest));
            test = "hi"; 
            application.EndRequest +=(new EventHandler(this.Application_EndRequest));


        }
       private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source,EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source ;
                HttpContext context = application.Context;
                context.Response.Write(test);
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a simple property, something like this ...

```
public MyConfig Config
{
    get
    {
        MyConfig _config = Application["MyConfig"] as MyConfig;
        if (_config == null)
        {
            _config = new MyConfig(...);
            Application["MyConfig"] = _config;
        }
        return _config;
    }
}
```

that way you just access whatever you need from Config via the property ...

```
int someValue = Config.SomeValue;
```

and it's loaded into the application object if it hasn't been already

If you need the config on a per-user basis rather than globally, then just use `Session["MyConfig"]` instead of `Application["MyConfig"]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but you might be able to implement this in the module's [init method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.init(v=VS.71).aspx).

Comment: I just tried it. It seems that that variables/objects etc in Init method are not available in HTTPmodule "hookable" events like Application_BeginRequest etc

Answer (score 0):

In the init method of your httpmodule you can hook up to the event in the context.

For example :

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {

        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Page p = context.Context.Handler as Page;
            if (p != null)
            {
            ///Code here    
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: just noticed there is no start event to hook upto, why not just populate the data in the init method of your http module...

Answer (score 0):

```
public SomeHttpModule : IHttpModule
{    
    private static readonly Configuration Configuration = 
            ConigurationReader.Read();    
}
```